# Installing Qubes 4.0.3 UEFI

Tags: qubes-os

Good evening, I am trying to install Qubes 4.0.3 as my primary system but am having issues. I am able to install the OS with legacy by disabling nouveau however there is no such option in UEFI (it's been removed)

I am stuck at a black screen and would appreciate any help.

Solved!

It seems that XEN was not playing well with my nvidia gpu, to fix this I opened "disk" (on linux) and mounted the XEN partition (called Anacoda). I opened the EFI folder and found the config file.

I added "nouveau.modeset=0" after the qubes-verbose section and it works!

I hope this helps any any all who wish to enjoy qubes!

[Error code](https://s.amsu.ng/BDvVUJm2qwiN)

Comment: You should provide us more information about the used hardware platform

Answer (score 0):

It seems that XEN was not playing well with my nvidia gpu, to fix this I opened "disk" (on linux) and mounted the XEN partition (called Anacoda). I opened the EFI folder and found the config file.

I added "nouveau.modeset=0" after the qubes-verbose section and it works!

I hope this helps any any all who wish to enjoy qubes!